# Component must be declared

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
  TYPE type_pledge IS TABLE OF DD_PLEDGE%rowtype 
    index by binary_integer;
  pledge_tab type_pledge;
  paystring varchar2(500);
BEGIN
  SELECT * BULK COLLECT
  INTO pledge_tab
  FROM DD_PLEDGE
  WHERE PLEDGEDATE >= '1-October-2012' AND PLEDGEDATE <= '31-October-2012';

  --Loop it
  FOR i in pledge_tab.first .. pledge_tab.last
  LOOP
    IF pledge_tab.paymonths = 0 THEN
      paystring := 'Lump Sum';
    ELSE
      paystring := 'Monthly Payments'; 
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Problem I'm having is that I can't seem to reference the 'paymonths' variable within the table variable containing data from the DD_PLEDGE table without an error coming up.

```
ORA-06550: line 15, column 19:
PLS-00302: component 'PAYMONTHS' must be declared
```

How do I solve this? I can't figure out how to reference it appropriately despite numerous hours of searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the subscript like `pledge_tab(i).paymonths`
Since only the row of `pledge_tab` has that defined.

```
  --Loop it
  FOR i in pledge_tab.first .. pledge_tab.last
  LOOP
    IF pledge_tab(i).paymonths = 0 THEN
      paystring := 'Lump Sum';
    ELSE
      paystring := 'Monthly Payments'; 
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
```

Comment: Huh, I cut that segment out of my block, repasted it, and now it works. Thanks. Probably just an error on how I was formatting it.